# Cell margin in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: xml, vba, powerpoint

I would like to design the below image as is in xml code. I used Dynamic for it. But couldn't create it as is. Please guide me on this. Thanks in advance.[image: po]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please update your post with sample VBA code you've tried so far.